# Unable to connect to wifi from Ubuntu 14.04! Realtek Problem!

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, connection

I changed from Windows XP to Ubuntu 14.04!
My netbook is 7 years old and i can't connect to WiFi!
It's first time i use Ubuntu so please be exact, if you want to help me!

*I did this `lspci` and the result was:*

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```

*The `lsusb` result was:*

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e1:0100 Syntek Semiconductor Co., Ltd 802.11g + Bluetooth Wireless Adapter
```

*The result of `sudo lshw -c network` is:*

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:e0:4c:50:a7:ba
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:25 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0100000-d0100fff memory:d0000000-d000ffff memory:d0120000-d013ffff
```

No internet found.

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 1):

**This is a repackaging of Realtek's own 8192CU USB WiFi driver for Ubuntu 13.10 and later

**Please check realteck for bugs in your wifi adapter before installing this driver generator.**

Dual antennas are known not to work well. This may be a Realtek driver issue.

Installation: You can copy and paste these commands in a terminal (Ctl + Alt + T) as long as you are an administrator.

Make sure you have the packages first.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
```

Then clone git.

```
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
```

Then set it as **DKMS** module:

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
```

Build & Install it:

```
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10
```

Refresh:

```
sudo depmod -a
```

Make sure the (broken) kernel driver is blacklisted:

```
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

Then reboot.

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I must have internet acces via cable? I tried these commads but they fail! Maybe i need to connect with cable first...

Comment: Yes you must have ability to download packages.

Comment: If This helped you(fixed the issue) please remember to click the CHeck MarK!

Comment: It didn't work! Its the same... http://i.stack.imgur.com/3gWiQ.png