# How can i remove Ubuntu? (delete/uninstall)

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall, delete

i have dual boot system! **Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and Windows Xp!**
I want to *delete* the Ubuntu and use only Windows Xp, because my netbook is too old and the wifi does not work with Ubuntu! I searched for a solution for a month and none worked! 
[Unfixable problem!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722176/unable-to-connect-to-wifi-from-ubuntu-14-04-realtek-problem)

Answer (score 0):

This is really a Windows question.  You need to learn how to delete the linux partition in Windows and potentially reinstall the bootloader if the linux one was installed over it.  You'll then also probably want to expand your Windows partition to reclaim the space the linux partition took.